# what are the technical parameters to generate nokia sms sound?

Tags: audio, nokia, sound-synthesis

Does anybody know the specs (or where to find them) for the traditional generic incoming SMS sound on Nokia phones (beep beep ..... beep beep .... )? (frequency, duration, pauses etc). seems, mobile phones of other makers have other sound palettes.
 
Capture/replay is too much overhead, when knowledge of some technical parameters would be enough.
making noise on a specific platform (java, .net) is not the problem here.

Answer (score 2):

The note played is a B<sup>b</sup>5, so that's 932.33Hz. Assuming BPM = 210, the note on and offs are at seconds

```
0.000 On
0.169 Off
0.285 On
0.454 Off
1.142 On
1.310 Off
1.428 On
1.596 Off
```

(Source: https://rs32tg.rapidshare.com/#!download|32dt|8016175|Message.mid|1|R~0)

I found an MP3 here: http://gallery.mobile9.com/f/62550/. The timbre of the sound is packed with overtones, but looking at the spectrum, it appears that even multiples are more prominent than odd multiples. Here's a linear spectrum taken from Audacity:

http://i55.tinypic.com/33mscg6.png